# how to compile iPhone sdk 3.0 project in iPhone sdk4

Tags: iphone

Just upgraded to iPhone sdk4 and getting a lot of errors in my iPhone sdk3.0 projects.

Here are some - 
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableURLRequest", referenced from:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UITabBar", referenced from:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:

about 66 errors ...

Any idea what is wrong here...

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Project Settings** -> **Build** and set **Base SDK** to **iPhone Device 4.0** and **iPhone OS Deployment Target** to **iPhone OS 3.0**

Comment: Thanks! one more thing when I modify XIB files and run the app in simulator the userinterface become blank (black color) any idea on this?

Comment: I've never dealt with it. Maybe you press Command+R in IB that just simulate interface?

Comment: when i change any other xib its not creating any problem.. but whenever i change the MainWindow.xib file. the view will not appear in the simulator...